# Python regex split function multiple delimiter

Tags: python, regex, linux

Here I am playing with python regex and here is my `uname` command output

```
$ uname -n
usa-ca-app01.example.com
```

Here is my python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from time import strftime
import commands

status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("uname -n")
backupfile = output.split('.')[0] + "-backup-" + strftime("%m-%d-%y")

print backupfile
```

Script output is:

```
$ ./backup.py
usa-ca-app01-backup-02-12-13
```

My Question: I want output like `app01-backup-02-12-13` so i wonder can we use multiple delimiter in `split` regex function to get required output or is there any good way to use elegant regex with python?

Comment: You may want to specify what general forms the hostname can take.

Comment: `import re; re.split("[-.]",a)[-3]`, where `a` is your string

Comment: You can use the `os` module to get the nodename: `os.uname()[1]`

Comment: @mlt: that's no advantage over `.rsplit('-', 1)[-1]`

Comment: @t-8ch: even better: `os.uname().nodename`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters only on Python 3

Comment: superb!!! Glad to see many python people.. with awesome answers!!

Comment: @martijn-pieters rsplit will return app01.example.com , so it is not enough. Anyway seems to me the question is not elaborate and does not demonstrate search efforts.

Comment: @mlt: I meant after splitting on the first `.`; `.split('.', 1)[0]` will be a little more efficient.

Comment: @MartijnPieters .rsplit('-', 1)[-1] doesn't giving me what i need

Comment: @mlt it should be re.split("[-.]",output)[-4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need regex, just use split two times:

```
output.split('.')[0].split('-')[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be a regex you could use split again:

```
backupfile = output.split('.')[0].split('-')[2] + "-backup-" + strftime("%m-%d-%y")
```

or maybe you could have multiple "-" delimiters and always wanted the last in case you could use:

```
subdomain = output.split('.')[0]
delimiter = "-"
subdomain_split = subdomain.split(delimiter)
split_length = len(subdomain_split)

backupfile = subdomain_split[split_length-1] + "-backup-" + strftime("%m-%d-%y")
```

Or with a regex:

```
regex = re.compile(".*-([a-zA-Z0-9]*).*",re.IGNORECASE)
r = regex.search(output)
backupfile = r.groups(0)[0] + "-backup-" + strftime("%m-%d-%y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Negligible difference between `split` with no `maxsplit` and `rsplit` with `maxsplit`

```
> python -m timeit "'usa-ca-app01.example.com'.split('.')[0].split('-',)[-1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.868 usec per loop
> python -m timeit "'usa-ca-app01.example.com'.split('.', 1)[0].rsplit('-', 1)[-1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.891 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have *very* consistant host names, and you just want the last portion...

First, instead of executing a uname command, use [os.uname](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) (that you already imported), then just have two splits like so:

```
hostname = os.uname()[1]
backupfile = hostname.split('.')[0].split('-')[2] + '-backup-' + strftime('%m-%d-%y')
```

Here is an output example:

```
>>> hostname.split('.')[0].split('-')[2] + '-backup-' + strftime('%m-%d-%y')
'app01-backup-02-12-13'
```

I would recommend using `%Y-%m-%d` though, it makes sorting by filename make more sense.

```
>>> hostname.split('.')[0].split('-')[2] + '-backup-' + strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'app01-backup-2013-02-12'
```

~tommy